# Video playing in html div

Tags: video, html5-video

I have following definition.

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="false" style="width:95%; height:300px;">
    <source src="https://youtu.be/4aYVLpY5FYU" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://youtu.be/4aYVLpY5FYU" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="https://youtu.be/4aYVLpY5FYU" type="video/webm">
    <object data="https://youtu.be/4aYVLpY5FYU" width="320" height="240">
          <embed src="https://youtu.be/4aYVLpY5FYU" width="320" height="240">
              Your browser does not support video
    </object>
</video>
```

Video is not playing at all.

**Note:**
I have got a list of 200 videos to be shown which are pointing to different sources, in addition to Youtube. Also, I will not know the type of the video (*ie:* MP4 or AVI or webM, etc).

Comment: The only permitted content allowed in a video tag are [source and track tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#technical_summary) -- any other tag (including a video tag) is invalid. Invalid HTML is a mixed bag sometimes it doesn't affect anything and under different circumstances nothing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always do it like this. Take a look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
 <embed type="video/webm" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZnuwB35GYMY" width="400" height="300"> 
</body>
</html>
```

You have to maintain the specific format of the link. And also the owner of the video has to permit embedding of that video on external source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know the type of the video.I have got a list of 200 videos to be shown which are pointing to different sources, in addition to youtube. Also, I will not know the type of the video i.e. mp4 or avi or webm etc.

Comment: You don't have to think about the format. Anyway if my answer solve your problem you are requested to select please.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Regarding *"Video is not playing at all."*

- Youtube links are pointing to a web page not a video file.
- You cannot use an HTML page in a video tag.
- For Youtube, replace the `<video> .... </video>` code with an `iframe` pointing to their **embed** player.

Example where your Youtube link has a video ID of `4aYVLpY5FYU` :

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4aYVLpY5FYU" 
></iframe>
```

**(2)**  Regarding *"I have got a list of 200 videos to be shown which are pointing to different sources"*.

The most reliable solution is to just give the `iframe` an ID so you can target it by JS code later on.

This means when your are ready to change the video to another link:

- target the `<iframe>` by its ID then change it's source `src= ...`

Example of a iframe with ID.

```
<iframe id="vid_container" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4aYVLpY5FYU" 
></iframe>
```

At this point you could have a `change_video( someParams );` function that expects a link as the function parameter. The function then changes the source of the iframe to the newly specified video URL (the function parameter).

```
change_video( "https://youtu.be/drQWopZDEEY" ); //# call the function
```

When called, the function does something like this.

```
function change_vid( inputPath )
{
    let container = document.getElementById("vid_container");
    container.src = inputPath;
    
}
```